# Why <input> shows default even if a default value has not been assigned?

Tags: html

I haven't set the form input default value, however I eveytime access the page, the form input text has default value. **This situation happens in Google chrome**, After I set autocomplete="off" in the input and form element. Firefox is ok now but Chrome is still displaying a default value.

This is my html code:

```html
<form id="add-host-form" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ip-addr">IP</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ip-addr">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="passwd">Passwd</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="passwd">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Every time I access the page, I got: I don't know where is the default value come and how to disable it?
[image]

Comment: Your browser is doing this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: Your browser auto-inputs it for you

Comment: Yellow box normally means autofill.

Answer (score 1):

These values are auto filled by browser that it had saved earlier.

You can clear your browser cache, stored passwords and saved form data to keep this from happening.

Comment: My browser is google chrome, and I have use **Clear browsing data**, and I  select [Browsing history cookies] [other site and plugin data] [cached images and files] and [Autofill form data selctions], it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-suggest/auto-complete is done by the browser based on your previous activities. To not have the browser do it . Set the element `autocomolete` property to `off`

`<input class="form-control" type="text" id="ip-addr" autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: I'm sorry to find that even I added **autocomplete="off"**, there still exists these default values

Answer (score 0):

Browsers autofill the form from the stored user id and password.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="ip-addr" autocomplete="off" />
```

The above may work in some browsers. However to support most of the browsers, the `autocomplete="off"` must be added in the `form` tag.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ip-addr" />
</form>
```

You can have a look at this for `autocomplete` support in chrome
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164

Answer (score 0):

for **password** use `autocomplete="new-password"` like the following:

```
<input required type="password" autocomplete="new-password" name="password"  />
```

and for **email** use `autocomplete="email"` like the following:

```
<input required type="email" autocomplete="email" name="email" />
```

for the rest of **the elements** use  `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser cache issue

1. Go to google Google chrome. chrome://settings/
2. select Google password manager
   [select Google password manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NNuB.png)

3.Search localhost
[Search localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqHKc.png)

4. delete the relevant entry
   [delete the relevant entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUBlv.png)